# How to fix: R project file is disappearing?

Tags: r, shiny

After while of developing a large forecasting app in R/Shiny, some strange incidents keep making me nervous.

Until recently everything worked just fine, but now sometimes when I am trying to close the app, by closing firefox (app displayed in browser) and after that pressing the stop button in RStudio, I get a warning message, that recommends me to restart the R session. After I did that, my R-project file disappeared.

I am running R on a parallels desktop (win10) and R as well as all packages are up to date.

This has happened several times now. Anyone got an idea, what might be the issue?

Now it even happens, when I first open RStudio, that an error message appears, stating that the project file does not longer exists:
[image]

Comment: Are you working on a copy or the original? Anything important I duplicate and work on the copy...

Comment: I made some backups of course, but the issue is just, that the project file gets deleted. All the scripts and rds files where left as they are